# Bootbox.confirm() dialog box is not showing up

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I am trying to use bootbox.confirm() for a simple confirmation box but dialog box is not showing up on the page. There are no problems in the chrome's console (in fact there is nothing in there). However when I click my button , for which the dialog box is supposed to appear, the additional div of the box can be seen in the elements section of the chrome's developer tools but nothing can be seen on the page.
here is the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#customers .js-delete").on("click", function () {
            var button = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Customer?", function (result) {
                if (result==true) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            button.parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

here is html of the page

```
<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Membership Type</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var customer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Edit", "Customers", new { id = customer.Id }, null)</td>
                <td>@customer.MembershipType.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <button data-customer-id="@customer.Id" class="btn btn-link js-delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have included Bootstrap js and css on your project? Because bootbox only works with that. (copying your code and adding bootstrap, it worked for me, check: https://jsfiddle.net/nsL4oxev/)

Comment: can you paste code of the html file here as well?

Comment: yes I have. I am using ASP .Net Mvc and I have included all the imports in my bundleconfig file @ClavinNunes

Comment: @nileshkumar I will post it wait a sec..

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to my environment and its works fine. Just make sure you did initialize the bootbox.js in the bundleConfig file under the bootstrap library other way the bootbox will not render in your page

"~/scripts/bootbox.js"